# 508 issue: Element is focusable but has or is contained by [aria-hidden=true] (ANDI Tool)

Tags: html, section508, andi

I'm using a third-party component which passes Axe 508, but does not pass the additional [ANDI](https://www.ssa.gov/accessibility/andi/help/install.html) tool.

The structure is as below, and the error is

```
Element is focusable but has or is contained by [aria-hidden=true].
```

It's a date picker which has an outer DIV. Underneath it is an internal **readonly** input text field used for its own purposes with **tabindex=-1** (not accessible via keyboard navigation). So why is it getting flagged as "element is focusable"? This element is not focusable. Should we disregard this ANDI warning?

[image]